# Un-nest data split in Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a Dataframe with 4 columns, the first column is a key, the 4th column is the value. But sometimes the key can have a variant, in that case the first column is empty, and the key and its variant are stored respectively in the 2nd and 3rd columns.

How can I transform my dataframe in order to have only 2 columns : keys and values?

Let's say for example I'm building a dataframe of residencies for my users, and I receive the following table:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [("Joe","", "", "London"),
    ("", "Alice", "Bob", "Paris" ),
    ("Sarah", "", "", "New-York"),
    ("", "John", "Edmund", "Berlin")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(single=x[0], partner1=x[1], partner2=x[2], town=x[3]))
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
schemaPeople.show()

 +--------+--------+------+--------+
 |partner1|partner2|single| town   | 
 +--------+--------+------+--------+
 |        |        |  Joe | London | 
 | Alice  | Bob    |      | Paris  | 
 |        |        | Sarah|New-York| 
 | John   | Edmund |      | Berlin |
 +--------+--------+------+--------+
```

How can I transform this into:

```
 +--------+--------+
 |   name | town   | 
 +--------+--------+
 | Joe    | London | 
 | Alice  | Paris  | 
 | Bob    | Paris  | 
 | Sarah  |New-York| 
 | John   | Berlin | 
 | Edmund | Berlin |
 +--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do `union`s

```py
df.select(
    F.col("partner1").alias("name"),
    F.col("town")
).where("name <> ''")\
.union(
    df.select(
        F.col("partner2").alias("name"),
        F.col("town")
    ).where("name <> ''")
)\
.union(
    df.select(
        F.col("single").alias("name"),
        F.col("town")
    ).where("name <> ''")
)
```

Comment: Great! I'm accepting your answer, given the fact that you spent time the other day to help me! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I could think of a way by concatenating the people using `concat_ws` and then `split` it. Then `explode` the result to get your table.

```
schpeep = schemaPeople. \
    select('town', func.split(func.concat_ws('|', 'partner1', 'partner2', 'single'), '\|').alias('people')). \
    withColumn('name', func.explode('people')). \
    drop('people'). \
    filter(func.col('name') != '')

schpeeps.show()

+--------+------+
|    town|  name|
+--------+------+
|  London|   Joe|
|   Paris| Alice|
|   Paris|   Bob|
|New-York| Sarah|
|  Berlin|  John|
|  Berlin|Edmund|
+--------+------+
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you, I find that Steven's is a bit easier to understand.